# No mathjax in the app!

Tags: feature-request, android-app, mathjax

Math isn't rendered on my Galaxy Note II in Math.SE when I access it through the new Android app. Is this a bug or has it just not been implemented yet?

[image: No math!]

Comment: No soup for you!

Comment: Help!!!!!!!!!!!